# Why does the dissolution of calcium hydroxide have a negative entropy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium, solubility, ionic-compounds

We had an experiment on the dissolution of calcium hydroxide and we obtained the experimental entropy value $\pu{-203 J mol^-1 K^-1}$ with a percent error of $26.7\%.$ Doesn't dissolving a solid in a solvent increase entropy?

Comment: It usually does increase the entropy, but compound solubility usually does increase with temperature. It is not the case of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$.

Answer (score 2):

When ionic compounds dissolve in water, water molecules form a complex ion around the calcium cation.  The presence of the hydroxide anion has a similar effect, though the polarities of the water ligands is reversed.
Thus, dissolution of Ca(OH)2 in water is actually a chemical reaction.  In some cases, complex ions may be more structured than the crystals of undissolved ions.       In such a case, the entropy change of solution will be negative.

Answer (score -2):

*Entropy* can be measured and aproached differently, (i) from an equation that relates entropy and *Enthalpy* to measure the heat of reaction, the remainder of the work done per degree of *Temperature* (°) is [image]

or if the change in enthalpy is measured then simply. [image]

*In this case the *Vector* of entropy has a negative direction hence an endothermic process and the magnitude is 203.*

(ii) Considering the amount of microstates, Boltzmann constant would relate the energy and the temperature, between solid and liquid dissolution; As a function of Omega (W). [image]

*For Omega (W) evaluate the microstates in your solid sample and the liquid volume using Boltzmann Relation.*

The change in Entropy between solid and liquid state is measure by Math approach, and is proven by Covention I and II (Physical Chemistry; Ira N. Levine Pg.295 6th Ed) for the Activity Coefficients on Gibbs free energy of standard solid state (S* solid 83.36 J/mol*K) and ideal model for gas state (S°gas,1 bar 285.62).

An increase in Entropy would be, then proven, as a solid State entropy is of approx. 83 J/mol*K and raise to 203 J/mol*K, through an endothermic process.

NIST Ca(OH)2 https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C1305620&Mask=FFF